# How do that (simple?) linq query

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, linq

I'm gonna simplified the db.
Here's what it looks like:

Tables:

```
Main: Products: ID, Ref, Price, 
Translation: ID, Product_ID, Language_ID, Name
Images: ID, Product_ID, Path, Index
```

I'm newbie with linq and I tried that to retrieve all products, their name with language_ID = 1 and the Image where Index = 1

```
From p In db.Products 
Join t In db.Translate_Products On p.ID_Product Equals t.Product_ID 
Join i In db.Images On p.ID_Product Equals i.Product_ID 
Where t.Language_ID = 1 And i.Index= 0 
Select p, t, i
```

Comment: You should ask _"How do I accept answers"_ ! **0 out of 10** impressive!

Comment: 13 questions, 0 accepts, you might want to consider reading how StackExchange works

Comment: Okay! I admit I never paid attention to that! Now I know it's important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
From p In db.Products 
Join t In db.Translate_Products On p.ID_Product equals t.Product_ID into results1
from r1 in results.DefaultIfEmpty()
Join i In db.Images On p.ID_Product equals i.Product_ID 
into results2
from r2 in results2.DefaultIfEmpty()
Where results.Language_ID = 1 And i.Index= 0 
Select new
{

Productid = p.Productid,
..
..
..
}
```

Comment: Actually I can't get it work... Visual studio doesnt allow me to have an "into" at the second line... Note sure to understand how it works neither...

Comment: into is valid in LINQ.. Verify if the p.ID_Product and t.Product_ID are of the same type.. And share the error message that you are getting..

Comment: Visual studio says "end of instruction excpected" (it's underlined in bleu )

Comment: It will be some syntax error.. you need to check it.. but surely not a keyword issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
From p In db.Products 
Join t In db.Translate_Products On p.ID_Product equals t.Product_ID 
into results1
from r1 in results1.DefaultIfEmpty()
Join i In db.Images On p.ID_Product equals i.Product_ID     
Where t.Language_ID == 1 And i.Index== 0 
Select new
{

Productid = p.Productid,
..
..
..
}
```

Comment: Thanx but still not working... Just writing From p In db.Products Join t In db.Translate_Products On p.ID_Product  Equals t.Product_ID  Into results1 give me an error for the into... Is it vb?

Comment: it is C# code.. i am using the same query but different tables and it works very fine for me.. don't know your case buddy..